# DRF created_by updated_by fail during migrations

Tags: django-models, django-rest-framework

I want to add an created_by and updated_by field to all my DB objects. I created a common model for this that will be used by most other objects. I have sorted out most obstacles so far. But the make migrations script ends with an error:

My model:

```
class CommonModel(models.Model):
"""Common fields that are shared among all models."""

    created_by = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.PROTECT,
                               editable=False, related_name="+")
    updated_by = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.PROTECT,
                               editable=False, related_name="+")
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,
                                  editable=False)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True,
                                  editable=False)
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Tag(CommonModel):
"""Tag to be used for device type"""
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

The error I get is :

> You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'created_by' to devicetype without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows).
> Please select a fix:
>
> 1. Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows with a null value for this column)
> 2. Quit, and let me add a default in models.py

The only "solution" I found searching the Internet was to define default='', run the makemigrations again and then manually edit the files afterwards to remove the default=''.
I cannot believe that this is the proper way to do this and that there is no solution for this yet.

Comment: That's not an error. It simply asks what it should do with `created_by` for the *existing* records. `default=''` makes no sense at all: that is a string, a `ForeignKey` only accepts a user object, or the primary key of a user object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set a default value for `created_at` and `update_at`, since they are not `null=True`.

The message you get during migration is not an error. If you want to provide a default value, select fix `1.`, it should show the below prompt,

```
Please enter the default value now, as valid Python
The datetime and ` modules are available, so you can do e.g. timezone.now
Type 'exit' to exit this prompt
>>>
```

Here you can set the default value using the `datetime` or `django.utils.timezone` module.

Comment: Thx to you and William. I did not realize that I did not purge the DB while testing the app.